# Disable "Click Continue to get access to this folder"

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I have an administrator account which doesn't have rights to access a folder.

When I try to do so I get "You don't currently have permissions to access this folder. Click Continue to get access to this folder".

I realise that an Admin can always edit the security settings and take ownership/grant access rights to get into the folder, but is it possible to prevent this "press continue to get access" button/window?

I'm on Server 2008 r1

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not. The window just elevates the rights of the explorer. The same way you can run notepad with elevated rights and browse straight into the folders.

Afaik you need to remove the permission to elevate the own rights to "disable" the message you. But the result is not an administrator account anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

The prompt is due to UAC.  How this works in 08/08R2 the administrator account must request an access token which is basically saying that you have the right to use your administrative rights.  If you disable UAC you are effectively saying just give me the rights I have, do not verify the action.

Answer (score 0):

Security through obscurity is *never* the answer.

If the user should not have access to the folder, don't grant them ability to change permissions on that folder.

If someone you don't trust has administrator access, there is a fundamental flaw in your organization which needs to be immediately addressed.